# rosconsole: log file bloated with ros topics, etc

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When we are using `ROS_DEBUG_STREAM()` macro, and the output is configured to screen, everything is fine. But when we configure it to log, and it goes to file, we get extremely bloated lines, like:

```
1530790045.295181299 DEBUG [/home/whoever/catkin_ws/src/module/src/basecontroller.cpp:175(SomeClass::setGoal) [topics: /rosout, /robotpose, /initialpose, /layers/sensors, /layers/plaser, /layers/plaser2, /layers/pultrasound, /layers/pcamera, /layers/cleaning, /hwctrl, /s_pi, /status/opbutton, /status/cleaned_sqm, /status/clean_rate, /status/clean_start, /status/hw_serial, /status/sw_version, /status/core_status, /status/alert, /twr, /mapfile, /layers/map, /layers/map_inflated, /layers/map_active, ...] SomeClass::setGoal(): new goal has been set (mx=446 my=308 theta=2.35619 speed=0)
```

instead of like:

```
1530790045.295181299 DEBUG SomeClass::setGoal(): new goal has been set (mx=446 my=308 theta=2.35619 speed=0)
```

Is there any way to force this behavior in log files?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296442/rosconsole:-log-file-bloated-with-ros-topics,-etc./) by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try messing with the configuration file as documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration). The full documentation of configuration is [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). Or you could write a regular expression to filter everything between brackets out, and pipe it to a new file ;)

---

Originally posted by [bouke](https://answers.ros.org/users/28943/bouke/) with karma: 61 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shardator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32772/shardator/) on 2018-07-06**:
Thanks. My only problem is that log4j is quite generic, while the topic listing is very ROS-specific. Also I'm not very sure how to do this for all nodes.